# Javascript - Slideshow doesn't move nor go into a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I've used W3School for this slideshow and I have it very similar, given that I've changed a few class names and ID names. However, my slideshow won't move past the second image nor will it go into a loop. I've looked at the other answered questions similar to this one, but have not found the answer.

Html

```
 <!-- Create: slider -->
<h1>Noticias Relevantes</h1>
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="fade">
    <div id="num-txt">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img\greenery.jpg">
    <div class="text">Nuevo viaje...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fade">
    <div id="num-txt">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img\snow.jpg">
    <div class="text">Expansion a nuevo paises...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fade">
    <div id="num-txt">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img\pink-church.jpg">
    <div class="text">Nuevo contrato con iglesia...</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dots">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<!-- Date -->
</div>

<div id="information">
  <h1>Informacion Importante</h1>
  <div id="infoList">
    <!-- Create: Drop down list -->
  </div>
</div>
<!--Right menu w/images as links -->

</body>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
// @ts-check

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("fade");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); //changes img every.
}
```

If it's possible please give a detailed explanation, I'd like to know as to why my code is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: You have a typo. Change `var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");` to `var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");`

Comment: Change `dots` ( theres just one ) to `dot` ( the three we need ) and it works ;)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that! I see why it's important to name classes and id's differently as to avoid 'these' types of issues. thank you all so MUCH, I was pulling hairs out of my head over this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work just change `dots` to `dot`. However, we could rewrite the code a bit to make it reusable / more bulletproof:

```
function showSlides(slides, dots) {
 if(slides.length !== dots.length) throw new Error("mismatch of element length");
 var slideIndex = 0;

 (function next(){  
   for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = i === slideIndex ? "block" : "none";
    if( i === slideIndex ){
     dots[i].classList.add("active");
    }else{
     dots[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
   }
   slideIndex = (slideIndex + 1) % slides.length;
   setTimeout(next, 2000); 
 })()
}
```

To start it do:

```
showSlides(
 document.getElementsByClassName("slides"),
 document.getElementsByClassName("dot")
);
```

Or using jquery ( maybe ):

```
showSlides( $(".slides"), $(".dot"));
```